# Load Balancer JSESSIONID issue while redirecting from https: to https: with some parameters causing invalid session()

Tags: java, https, jvm, load-balancing, f5

I am facing below issue with respect to F5 LoadBalancing-LB that is configured in my application.

1. I host my application A with https:// Loadbalancing , when i click some link in it , It will redirect to another Application B with some parameters and with JSESSIONID of application A. Application B is also hosted on another https:// LoadBalancing-LB. But, JSESSIONID info of Application A is lost when we go to Application B and while returning back from Application B to Application A, entirely new JSESSIONID being created in application A and causing Invalid session.
2. Where as if i use JVM links to do the same above process its working like a charm. When I click on a link in application A via https:// jvm URL , it will redirects to application B hosted on another https:// loadbalancing. But, JSESSIONID of application A is retained this time and when redirect back from application B to A , still old application A's JSESSIONID is still valid.At last landing URL of application A is now, not a LB url but its a webserver url.(LB-->webserver-->jvm)

suspecting on application A's LB url doing some crazy things.. It would be great if any LB/F5 analyst/experts spread some light over here to fix this LB issue..

Answer (score 0):

Any redirects that go directly to the server are occurring on the server, not the LB.

Server Changes:

1. Application servers > App_A_and_B> Web container > Custom properties :
   -> Add "httpsIndicatorHeader - true"
2. Application servers > App_A_and_B > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties
   -> Add " HttpSessionIdReuse - true"
3. Restart all the JVMs....
   LB Changes :
   Disable Session Persistence on LB